# Getting complete ZIP Code using reverseGeocodeLocation

Tags: ios, zipcode

I have used `reverseGeocodeLocation` to get zip code from, however, it returns only five digits, example: "94112".
But here in Brazil, we have zip code with eight digits, example "08750630", but the aftermath is "08750".

How to solve this? is it possible?

My Code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = newLocation.coordinate;

    lastLat = coords.latitude;
    lastLng = coords.longitude;

    CLGeocoder *reverse = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coords.latitude
                                                      longitude:coords.longitude];
    lastAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
    lblAccuracy.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lastAccuracy];

    if(lastAccuracy <= 10)
    {
        [reverse reverseGeocodeLocation:location
                      completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                          if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
                              CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                              strCEP = place.postalCode;
                              strLastSubLocation = place.subLocality;
                              strLastLocation = place.locality;
                              strEndereco = place.thoroughfare;
                              lblEndereco.text = strEndereco;
                              ];
                          }
                      }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to get the full postal code number accessing the `addressDictionary` property from `CLPlacemark`.

In this `NSDictionary` we can get the information we need in the values from the keys: `ZIP` and `PostCodeExtension`.